# Shaka Player: ignore empty AdaptationSet

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, mpeg-dash, shaka

I'm trying to play DASH stream in Shaka Player.
Sometimes the stream doesn't have an audio source and its manifest file contains an empty `AdaptationSet` entry.
In this case Shaka Player returns the manifest parsing error:

`| DASH_EMPTY_ADAPTATION_SET | 4003 | number |  The DASH Manifest contained an AdaptationSet with no Representations. |`

**Is it possible to ignore this error somehow and play the video without audio source?**

Example of manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MPD xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    xsi:schemaLocation="urn:mpeg:DASH:schema:MPD:2011 http://standards.iso.org/ittf/PubliclyAvailableStandards/MPEG-DASH_schema_files/DASH-MPD.xsd"
    profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011"
    type="dynamic"
    minimumUpdatePeriod="PT4S"
    suggestedPresentationDelay="PT4S"
    availabilityStartTime="2019-06-24T13:38:04Z"
    publishTime="2019-06-24T13:38:34Z"
    timeShiftBufferDepth="PT14.9S"
    minBufferTime="PT9.9S">
    <ProgramInformation>
        <Title>Media Presentation</Title>
    </ProgramInformation>
    <Period id="0" start="PT0.0S">
        <AdaptationSet id="0" contentType="video" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true">
            <Representation id="0" mimeType="video/mp4" codecs="avc1.640028" bandwidth="2000000" width="1920" height="1080" frameRate="20/1">
                <SegmentTemplate timescale="10240" initialization="init-stream$RepresentationID$.m4s" media="chunk-stream$RepresentationID$-$Number%05d$.m4s" startNumber="5">
                    <SegmentTimeline>
                        <S t="201697" d="51190" r="2" />
                    </SegmentTimeline>
                </SegmentTemplate>
            </Representation>
        </AdaptationSet>
        <AdaptationSet id="1" contentType="audio" segmentAlignment="true" bitstreamSwitching="true">
        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

Comment: Can you post some of your code, please?